# How can I use typescript Triple-Slash Directives in Vue project for type definitions?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

The structure of my project is as follows:

- node_modules

  - ...
  - vue

    - dist

      - vue.d.ts
- src

  - utils

    - index.ts

The code for my index.ts is as follows:

```
/// <reference path = "../../node_modules/vue/dist/vue.d.ts" />

export function fn(p: ComponentOptions) {
  // other code...
}
```

Editor(VSCode) prompts for name `ComponentOptions` not found.

I want the effect of the above code to be the same as the effect of the following code.

```
import type { ComponentOptions } from "vue";

export function fn(p: ComponentOptions) {
  // other code...
}
```

Is there a mistake in the way I use it? How can I get the ts triple slash code to work properly?

Comment: Why do you *need* triple-slash directives?

Comment: For importing declaration files. @vr.

Comment: Why not just use a regular import like you've shown?